# modified designer.vb of Forms.UserControl in code editor, now design view not visible in visual studio 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How can i recover my designer view. I mistakenly edited the auto-generated designer class by implementing the eventhandlers. Next time i opened up the Vistual Studio project, the design view is missing. I am not able to find a way to get back the Design view.

Here is my Control_IncidentWatcher.Designer.vb file

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class Controls_IncidentWatcher
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

    'UserControl overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
...
...
...
    Private Sub c_playsample_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles c_playsample.Click
        SoundAndAlerts.SetVolume(c_Volume.SelectedItem.ToString())

        SoundAndAlerts.PlayAlert(c_Loops.SelectedItem.ToString(), c_CustomSound.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            c_CustomSound.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image: Control_IncidentWatcher]

As you can see the designer,vb and resx have got disassociated.

**Update:**

I added another user control test_usercontrol.vb and try to mimic all the configuration in my Control_IncidentWatcher
On opening project, my Control_IncidentWatcher changes from UserControl to a normal VB file in about 2 seconds. I was able to capture the change
[image: Change in appearance]

Also my project.vb file changes

```
<Compile Include="test_usercontrol.Designer.vb">
  <DependentUpon>test_usercontrol.vb</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="test_usercontrol.vb">
  <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
</Compile>

<Compile Include="Control_IncidentWatcher.Designer.vb">
  <DependentUpon>Control_IncidentWatcher.vb</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Control_IncidentWatcher.vb" />
```

The SubType attribute is getting removed from the Control_IncidentWatcher on opening the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the internet, there is a manual fix.

You open the project file in an XML editor and add the following element to
 the affected parts...

e.g. affected parts:

form1.vb

form1.designer.vb

form1.resx

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Forms\form1.designer.vb">
<DependentUpon>form1.vb</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>

<EmbeddedResource Include="Forms\form1.resx">
<DependentUpon>form1.vb</DependentUpon>
<SubType>Designer</SubType>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me look at the right direction. The form had lost the <subtype> attribute of UserControl which i realized by adding a dummy UserControl form in the project. Also i had some how messed up the class definitions, so even after adding the xml entries, visual studio was reverting the Usercontrol form as a normal vb file

Answer (score 1):

This is really embarrassing, the class definition inside the Control_IncidentWatcher.Designer.vb was different from the Control_IncidentWatcher.vb 
.I must have recreated this definition in trying to resolve the issue.

```
Partial Class Controls_IncidentWatcher
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
```

where as the class definition inside the UserControl form was

```
Public Class Control_IncidentWatcher
End Class
```

There was mismatch in the class names. I also made the names of the class and the files consistent. This was finally resolved of course after adding the Subtype back in the project.vb file